# Spring boot jpa project refer service to another project

Tags: spring-boot

I have 2 spring boot apps. One is used as SDK for reusing the component to any spring boot project.And the second project will use the SDK project and use its component.That's the basic idea. The issue I getting dependency not found an exception.

SDK project will have some entities and their repository and services.it will not have any DB configuration in application.properties because it will refer to the second project, which will have another DB. So i have configured 2 DB in the second project.

**dbconfig snippet**

```
sdk.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
sdk.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/organization
sdk.datasource.username=root
sdk.datasource.password=password



hrms.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hrms.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.188:3306/hrms
hrms.datasource.username = root
hrms.datasource.password = hY6hvg
```

When I autowire the sdk services on the second project controller like

```
@Autowired
    private SDKUserService sdkUserService;
```

it will show dependency not found an exception.

Below is my SDK user service from SDK project.

```
 @Service
    public class SDKUserServiceImpl implements SDKUserService {   
    //
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you update image showing your directory structure.

Comment: @ramvinoth updated.

Answer (score 1):

Your both projects are maintaing different application context. so what your are not gaining access to the class from bean context by using @Autowired. So as to acheive this you have to maintain both projects classes in single context of the spring just by doing either in xml or java configuration file as below.

```
<import resource="classpath:projectBweb.xml"/>
```

or

```
 @Import({ projectB.class })
```

Comment: So how do I call service in controller

Comment: same as usual, If you imported the xml config file of one project into other the spring bean manage a single context with instance of all classes in both project. son you can call as using @Autowired

Comment: The real issue is repository is not creating because of the database connection. The connection details are on the second project, not in SDK project.

Comment: so you are querying database from service layer of second project. for that purpose you are calling service of second project from controller of first project for that case your first project context must hold the classes in second project that favors your dependency injection.

Comment: So try importing the xml configuration of second project into xml of first project.

Comment: This is a spring boot application, so no XML configuration.

Comment: Try adding the second project into the first project build path.